# How to get value from TextView and Radio button in RecyclerView on click Button?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-radiobutton

How to get value in an array list from Textview  and radio button in RecyclerView on click button

when clicking on button then store in an array list please help me

[image]

Comment: By using `if {rb.isChecked()....`

Comment: you have to maintain a list of objects when the value change updates the model using notifydatasetChanged and on clicking on submit button get the values.

Answer (score 1):

Question is not clear. From where you want to store a data as an array ? From checkbox  and where is your text - is it question of your text or what ? Pal, if you want to collect data from check box then you can use `onCheckChangeListener`.
On this .

```
final List<String> mList = new ArrayList<>();
 mList.add("Your value");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your button is in `Fragment` (or `Activity`) and your radio button is in an item of `RecyclerView`.

You can do like

**If your RecyclerView is recyclable**

- User select the radio button
- You will receive the selected item by `setOnCheckedChangeListener`
- You save this value to a field in Adapter (you can save to a `list`, `map`, or any other datatype you like)
- When you click at Button, you can get this value like `adapter.`

**If your RecyclerView is not recyclable**

You don't need to save any value.

When click at `Button`, you can get `RecyclerView` item -> then get `RadioGroup` -> get selected RadioButton.